# C# - How to validate the user input for a calculator if the user inputs a wrong input?

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

I am making a simple calculator app in c# and I have run into a problem where if the user inputs for example "4**3" the program crashes. Is there any way to validate the input so it would flag up if the user entered something that can not be calculated?

```
string sum = textDisplay.Text;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var ans = dt.Compute(sum, "");
```

Comment: Sure, add a `try...catch`

Comment: Once you have an operator, change it only if it's a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Tim, use a Try/Catch block.  Obviously this tells you if it failed AFTER the attempt, but the exception does give you some information:

```
string operation = "4**3";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    var ans = dt.Compute(operation, "");
    MessageBox.Show(ans.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Operation: " + operation + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Operation Failed");
}
```

The above produced:

[image]

If you want to know if it will fail before the call to `Compute()`, you'd have to write your own syntax parser...which kinda negates the whole point of using `Compute()` in the first place.

Comment: Actually, a regular expression, and it can simply check whether there are two or more operators in a row in between numbers, is a way to catch it before the call to `Compute()`, but yes, catching the exception requires no work.

Comment: @insane_developer Just depends on how complex your operations can get.  If we only ever have two operands with one operator in-between, then it'd be easy.  If we get more complicated expressions with parenthesis, for example, then your regular expression is going to get complicated very quickly.  With parens, repeats are allowed, `((5-4)*(1-5)`, and note there are no longer any numbers to the left/right of the `*`.

Comment: Sure, but adding parentheses to the expression would not be overly complicated. There are well defined patterns to look for, in the case of parentheses. There's only so far I would go to prevent bad form, though. You can argue that if a try catch has to be there anyway, you might as well rely on it entirely. It's all debatable, l guess.